# How to generate a "thick" bezier curve?

Tags: geometry, bezier

I'm looking for a way to generate a polygon programatically by "thickening" a Bezier curve. Something like this:

[image: thick bezier curve]

My initial idea was to find the normals in the line, and generate the polygon from them:

[image: Bezier normals]

But the problem is that the normals can cross each other in steep curves, like this:

[image: Bezier normals crossing each other]

Are there any formulas or algorithms that generate a polygon from a bezier curve? I couldn't find any information on the internet, but perhaps I'm searching using the wrong words...

Comment: This might help: http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/02/18/drawing-bezier-curves/

Comment: This question [has been](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148831/how-to-offset-a-cubic-bezier-curve) [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408457/outline-of-cubic-bezier-curve-stroke) [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017144/how-to-make-a-parallel-bezier-curve-heuristically).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a constant thickness, this is called an offset curve and your idea of using normals is correct.

This indeed raises two difficulties:

1. The offset curve is not exactly representable as a Bezier curve; you can use a polyline instead, or retrofit Beziers to the polyline;
2. There are indeed cusps appearing when the radius of curvature becomes smaller than the offset width. You will have to detect the self-intersections of the polyline.

As far as I know, there is no easy solution.

For a little more info, check [38. Curve offsetting](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#offsetting).

Comment: Another term can be of interest to you: flattening. This is the process of decomposing a curve in small line segments. Also see http://sibgrapi.sid.inpe.br/col/sid.inpe.br/banon/2004/08.13.18.12/doc/BezierOffsetRendering.pdf.

Answer (score 5):

Step-by-step process detailed here: [How to Draw an Offset Curve](http://brunoimbrizi.com/unbox/2015/03/offset-curve/)

Solution based on the paper ‘[Quadratic bezier offsetting with selective subdivision](http://microbians.com/math/Gabriel_Suchowolski_Quadratic_bezier_offsetting_with_selective_subdivision.pdf)‘ by Gabriel Suchowolski. More from the author: [MATH+CODE](https://microbians.com/mathcode)

Interactive example: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/brunoimbrizi/pen/VYEWgY)

```js
var canvas, ctx;
var drags;
var thickness = 30;
var drawControlPoints = true;
var useSplitCurve = true;

function init() {
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);

  drags = [];

  window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
  window.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);

  document.getElementById('btnControl').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    drawControlPoints = !drawControlPoints
  });
  document.getElementById('btnSplit').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    useSplitCurve = !useSplitCurve
  });

  resize();
  draw();

  var positions = [{
    x: canvas.width * 0.3,
    y: canvas.height * 0.4
  }, {
    x: canvas.width * 0.35,
    y: canvas.height * 0.85
  }, {
    x: canvas.width * 0.7,
    y: canvas.height * 0.25
  }];
  for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
    drags.push(new Drag(ctx, new Vec2D(positions[i].x, positions[i].y)));
  }
}

function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  ctx.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < drags.length; i++) {
    d = drags[i];
    d.draw();
  }

  for (var i = 1; i < drags.length - 1; i++) {
    /*
    var d1 = (i == 0) ? drags[i].pos : drags[i - 1].pos;
    var d2 = drags[i].pos;
    var d3 = (i == drags.length - 1) ? drags[drags.length - 1].pos : drags[i + 1].pos;

    var v1 = d2.sub(d1);
    var v2 = d3.sub(d2);
    var p1 = d2.sub(v1.scale(0.5));
    var p2 = d3.sub(v2.scale(0.5));
    var c = d2;
    */
    var p1 = drags[i - 1].pos;
    var p2 = drags[i + 1].pos;
    var c = drags[i].pos;

    var v1 = c.sub(p1);
    var v2 = p2.sub(c);

    var n1 = v1.normalizeTo(thickness).getPerpendicular();
    var n2 = v2.normalizeTo(thickness).getPerpendicular();

    var p1a = p1.add(n1);
    var p1b = p1.sub(n1);
    var p2a = p2.add(n2);
    var p2b = p2.sub(n2);

    var c1a = c.add(n1);
    var c1b = c.sub(n1);
    var c2a = c.add(n2);
    var c2b = c.sub(n2);

    var line1a = new Line2D(p1a, c1a);
    var line1b = new Line2D(p1b, c1b);
    var line2a = new Line2D(p2a, c2a);
    var line2b = new Line2D(p2b, c2b);

    var split = (useSplitCurve && v1.angleBetween(v2, true) > Math.PI / 2);

    if (!split) {
      var ca = line1a.intersectLine(line2a).pos;
      var cb = line1b.intersectLine(line2b).pos;
    } else {
      var t = MathUtils.getNearestPoint(p1, c, p2);
      var pt = MathUtils.getPointInQuadraticCurve(t, p1, c, p2);

      var t1 = p1.scale(1 - t).add(c.scale(t));
      var t2 = c.scale(1 - t).add(p2.scale(t));

      var vt = t2.sub(t1).normalizeTo(thickness).getPerpendicular();
      var qa = pt.add(vt);
      var qb = pt.sub(vt);

      var lineqa = new Line2D(qa, qa.add(vt.getPerpendicular()));
      var lineqb = new Line2D(qb, qb.add(vt.getPerpendicular()));

      var q1a = line1a.intersectLine(lineqa).pos;
      var q2a = line2a.intersectLine(lineqa).pos;
      var q1b = line1b.intersectLine(lineqb).pos;
      var q2b = line2b.intersectLine(lineqb).pos;
    }

    if (drawControlPoints) {
      // draw control points
      var r = 2;
      ctx.beginPath();
      if (!split) {
        ctx.rect(ca.x - r, ca.y - r, r * 2, r * 2);
        ctx.rect(cb.x - r, cb.y - r, r * 2, r * 2);
      } else {
        // ctx.rect(pt.x - r, pt.y - r, r * 2, r * 2);
        ctx.rect(p1a.x - r, p1a.y - r, r * 2, r * 2);
        ctx.rect(q1a.x - r, q1a.y - r, r * 2, r * 2);
        ctx.rect(p2a.x - r, p2a.y - r, r * 2, r * 2);
        ctx.rect(q2a.x - r, q2a.y - r, r * 2, r * 2);
        ctx.rect(qa.x - r, qa.y - r, r * 2, r * 2);

        ctx.rect(p1b.x - r, p1b.y - r, r * 2, r * 2);
        ctx.rect(q1b.x - r, q1b.y - r, r * 2, r * 2);
        ctx.rect(p2b.x - r, p2b.y - r, r * 2, r * 2);
        ctx.rect(q2b.x - r, q2b.y - r, r * 2, r * 2);
        ctx.rect(qb.x - r, qb.y - r, r * 2, r * 2);

        ctx.moveTo(qa.x, qa.y);
        ctx.lineTo(qb.x, qb.y);
      }
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#0072bc';
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fillStyle = '#0072bc';
      ctx.fill();

      // draw dashed lines
      ctx.beginPath();
      if (!split) {
        ctx.moveTo(p1a.x, p1a.y);
        ctx.lineTo(ca.x, ca.y);
        ctx.lineTo(p2a.x, p2a.y);

        ctx.moveTo(p1b.x, p1b.y);
        ctx.lineTo(cb.x, cb.y);
        ctx.lineTo(p2b.x, p2b.y);
      } else {
        ctx.moveTo(p1a.x, p1a.y);
        ctx.lineTo(q1a.x, q1a.y);
        ctx.lineTo(qa.x, qa.y);
        ctx.lineTo(q2a.x, q2a.y);
        ctx.lineTo(p2a.x, p2a.y);

        ctx.moveTo(p1b.x, p1b.y);
        ctx.lineTo(q1b.x, q1b.y);
        ctx.lineTo(qb.x, qb.y);
        ctx.lineTo(q2b.x, q2b.y);
        ctx.lineTo(p2b.x, p2b.y);
      }
      ctx.setLineDash([2, 4]);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.setLineDash([]);
    }

    // central line
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(c.x, c.y, p2.x, p2.y);
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#959595';
    ctx.stroke();

    // offset curve a
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(p1a.x, p1a.y);
    if (!split) {
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(ca.x, ca.y, p2a.x, p2a.y);
    } else {
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(q1a.x, q1a.y, qa.x, qa.y);
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(q2a.x, q2a.y, p2a.x, p2a.y);
    }
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#0072bc';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();

    // offset curve b
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(p1b.x, p1b.y);
    if (!split) {
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(cb.x, cb.y, p2b.x, p2b.y);
    } else {
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(q1b.x, q1b.y, qb.x, qb.y);
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(q2b.x, q2b.y, p2b.x, p2b.y);
    }
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#0072bc';
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function resize() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

function mousedown(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var m = new Vec2D(e.clientX, e.clientY);

  for (var i = 0; i < drags.length; i++) {
    var d = drags[i];
    var dist = d.pos.distanceToSquared(m);
    if (dist < d.hitRadiusSq) {
      d.down = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}

function mouseup() {
  for (var i = 0; i < drags.length; i++) {
    var d = drags[i];
    d.down = false;
  }
}

function mousemove(e) {
  var m = new Vec2D(e.clientX, e.clientY);

  for (var i = 0; i < drags.length; i++) {
    var d = drags[i];
    if (d.down) {
      d.pos.x = m.x;
      d.pos.y = m.y;
      break;
    }
  }
}

function Drag(ctx, pos) {
  this.ctx = ctx;
  this.pos = pos;
  this.radius = 6;
  this.hitRadiusSq = 900;
  this.down = false;
}

Drag.prototype = {
  draw: function() {
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    this.ctx.closePath();
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = '#959595'
    this.ctx.stroke();
  }
}

// http://toxiclibs.org/docs/core/toxi/geom/Vec2D.html
function Vec2D(a, b) {
  this.x = a;
  this.y = b;
}

Vec2D.prototype = {
  add: function(a) {
    return new Vec2D(this.x + a.x, this.y + a.y);
  },
  angleBetween: function(v, faceNormalize) {
    if (faceNormalize === undefined) {
      var dot = this.dot(v);
      return Math.acos(this.dot(v));
    }
    var theta = (faceNormalize) ? this.getNormalized().dot(v.getNormalized()) : this.dot(v);
    return Math.acos(theta);
  },
  distanceToSquared: function(v) {
    if (v !== undefined) {
      var dx = this.x - v.x;
      var dy = this.y - v.y;
      return dx * dx + dy * dy;
    } else {
      return NaN;
    }
  },
  dot: function(v) {
    return this.x * v.x + this.y * v.y;
  },
  getNormalized: function() {
    return new Vec2D(this.x, this.y).normalize();
  },
  getPerpendicular: function() {
    return new Vec2D(this.x, this.y).perpendicular();
  },
  interpolateTo: function(v, f) {
    return new Vec2D(this.x + (v.x - this.x) * f, this.y + (v.y - this.y) * f);
  },
  normalize: function() {
    var mag = this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y;
    if (mag > 0) {
      mag = 1.0 / Math.sqrt(mag);
      this.x *= mag;
      this.y *= mag;
    }
    return this;
  },
  normalizeTo: function(len) {
    var mag = Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
    if (mag > 0) {
      mag = len / mag;
      this.x *= mag;
      this.y *= mag;
    }
    return this;
  },
  perpendicular: function() {
    var t = this.x;
    this.x = -this.y;
    this.y = t;
    return this;
  },
  scale: function(a) {
    return new Vec2D(this.x * a, this.y * a);
  },
  sub: function(a, b) {
    return new Vec2D(this.x - a.x, this.y - a.y);
  },
}

// http://toxiclibs.org/docs/core/toxi/geom/Line2D.html
function Line2D(a, b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
}

Line2D.prototype = {
  intersectLine: function(l) {
    var isec,
      denom = (l.b.y - l.a.y) * (this.b.x - this.a.x) - (l.b.x - l.a.x) * (this.b.y - this.a.y),
      na = (l.b.x - l.a.x) * (this.a.y - l.a.y) - (l.b.y - l.a.y) * (this.a.x - l.a.x),
      nb = (this.b.x - this.a.x) * (this.a.y - l.a.y) - (this.b.y - this.a.y) * (this.a.x - l.a.x);
    if (denom !== 0) {
      var ua = na / denom,
        ub = nb / denom;
      if (ua >= 0.0 && ua <= 1.0 && ub >= 0.0 && ub <= 1.0) {
        isec = new Line2D.LineIntersection(Line2D.LineIntersection.Type.INTERSECTING, this.a.interpolateTo(this.b, ua));
      } else {
        isec = new Line2D.LineIntersection(Line2D.LineIntersection.Type.NON_INTERSECTING, this.a.interpolateTo(this.b, ua));
      }
    } else {
      if (na === 0 && nb === 0) {
        isec = new Line2D.LineIntersection(Line2D.LineIntersection.Type.COINCIDENT, undefined);
      } else {
        isec = new Line2D.LineIntersection(Line2D.LineIntersection.Type.COINCIDENT, undefined);
      }
    }
    return isec;
  }
}

Line2D.LineIntersection = function(type, pos) {
  this.type = type;
  this.pos = pos;
}

Line2D.LineIntersection.Type = {
  COINCIDENT: 0,
  PARALLEL: 1,
  NON_INTERSECTING: 2,
  INTERSECTING: 3
};


window.MathUtils = {
  getPointInQuadraticCurve: function(t, p1, pc, p2) {
    var x = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * p1.x + 2 * (1 - t) * t * pc.x + t * t * p2.x;
    var y = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * p1.y + 2 * (1 - t) * t * pc.y + t * t * p2.y;

    return new Vec2D(x, y);
  },

  // http://microbians.com/math/Gabriel_Suchowolski_Quadratic_bezier_offsetting_with_selective_subdivision.pdf
  // http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/
  getNearestPoint: function(p1, pc, p2) {
    var v0 = pc.sub(p1);
    var v1 = p2.sub(pc);

    var a = v1.sub(v0).dot(v1.sub(v0));
    var b = 3 * (v1.dot(v0) - v0.dot(v0));
    var c = 3 * v0.dot(v0) - v1.dot(v0);
    var d = -1 * v0.dot(v0);

    var p = -b / (3 * a);
    var q = p * p * p + (b * c - 3 * a * d) / (6 * a * a);
    var r = c / (3 * a);

    var s = Math.sqrt(q * q + Math.pow(r - p * p, 3));
    var t = MathUtils.cbrt(q + s) + MathUtils.cbrt(q - s) + p;

    return t;
  },

  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810765/calculating-cubic-root-for-negative-number
  cbrt: function(x) {
    var sign = x === 0 ? 0 : x > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    return sign * Math.pow(Math.abs(x), 1 / 3);
  }
}

init();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

canvas {
  display: block
}

#btnControl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#btnSplit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btnControl">control points on/off</button>
<button type="button" id="btnSplit">split curve on/off</button>
```

Comment: This is very elegant. I have been doing with an approximate solution for a long time. Your solution is very useful for what I am working in.

Comment: Thanks for using my method, for more information about this please go to my math section at https://microbians.com/mathcode

Answer (score 2):

This is a hard problem. There are reasonable approximations like Tiller-Hanson (see my answer to this question: [How to get the outline of a stroke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643864/how-to-get-the-outline-of-a-stroke)) but the questioner specifically raises the difficulty that 'the normals can cross each other in steep curves'; another way of looking at it is that an envelope created using normals can produce an indefinitely large number of loops, depending on how closely spaced the normals are.

A perfect solution, without self-intersections, is the envelope of the [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) of a circle and the line. I think it's impractical to get such an envelope, though: you may have to accept the intersections.

Another interesting but daunting fact is that, as Richard Kinch notes in [MetaFog: Converting METAFONT Shapes to Contours](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb16-3/tb48kinc.pdf), "Algebra tells us
that stroking a 3rd degree polynomial curve (the ellipse
approximated by Bézier curves) along a 3rd
degree polynomial curve (the Bézier curve of the
stroked path) results in a 6th degree envelope curve.
We will have to approximate these 6th degree exact
envelope curves with 3rd degree (Bezier) curves".

Answer (score 2):

Here I had the math papers about that theme.

The “Quadratic bezier offsetting with selective subdivision" covers a method to offset quadratic beziers using a criterion that set the parametric value on which the quadratic bezier is subdivided at the start in order to generate an offset approximation with other quadratic beziers segments. This method, obviously, may not be the most perfect approximation of a hypothetical “real” offset, but a fast algorithm for drawing strokes that can be performed on different quality levels by using a non recursive algorithm.

Here all the papers and examples https://microbians.com/mathcode
that imbrizi use for the codepen he put in the answers.

https://codepen.io/microbians/pen/OJPmBZg

```
code in the link
```

[image]